# flutter cant download 'flutter_patched_sdk' tools

Tags: android, flutter

I recently upgraded flutter to 1.20.4 , when I try to create a new project in android studio I get this error

> Download failed. URL: https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/flutter/d1bc06f032f9d6c148ea6b96b48261d6f545004f/flutter_patched_sdk.zip Error: 403 Forbidden

and android studio don't know my android device

when I run `flutter doctor -v` flutter start downloading `flutter_patched_sdk tools`  but cant download it

```
     C:\Users\raZor>flutter doctor -v
     Downloading flutter_patched_sdk tools...
     Download failed.
     URL:                   
     https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/flutter/d1bc06f032f9d6c148ea6b96b48261d6f545004f/flutter_patched_sdk.zip
     Error: 403 Forbidden
     
     #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
     #1      Net._attempt (package:flutter_tools/src/base/net.dart:148:9)
     <asynchronous suspension>
     #2      Net.fetchUrl (package:flutter_tools/src/base/net.dart:63:33)
     #3      Cache.downloadFile (package:flutter_tools/src/cache.dart:492:16)
     #4      CachedArtifact._downloadArchive.<anonymous closure>(package:flutter_tools/src/cache.dart:640:23)
     #5      CachedArtifact._downloadArchive.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/cache.dart:636:55)
     #6      CachedArtifact._withDownloadFile (package:flutter_tools/src/cache.dart:670:26)
     #7      CachedArtifact._downloadArchive (package:flutter_tools/src/cache.dart:636:12)
     #8      CachedArtifact._downloadZipArchive (package:flutter_tools/src/cache.dart:657:12)
     #9      EngineCachedArtifact.updateInner (package:flutter_tools/src/cache.dart:795:13)
     #10     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
     #11     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
     #12     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
     #13     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
     #14     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
     #15     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
     #16     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
     #17     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
     #18     CachedArtifact._withDownloadFile (package:flutter_tools/src/cache.dart)
     #19     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
     #20     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
     #21     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
     #22     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
     #23     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
     #24     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
     #25     Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)
     #26     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
     #27     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
     #28     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
     #29     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
     #30     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
     #31     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
     #32     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
     #33     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)
```

Did anyone see this?

Answer (score 1):

Solution found!

...after spending a another hour, i for found [this post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99628#issuecomment-1072910852)

Basically the solution, was. remove cache-dir from flutter-home, and then run flutter --version

All good.

And for my initial prob. with docker, the end result was:

```
RUN cd /root/opt \
  && git clone -b master https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git \
  && rm -rf /root/opt/flutter/bin/cache \
  && flutter --version
```

Comment: which Flutter docker image do you use? Or do you have your dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience as an Iranian which is under many sanctions, seems this issue is related to your connectivity problems. For the countries like Iran targeted by US sanctions, Google has limited or blocked accessing many of it's services.

Try to use a proxy server and test it again.

The other problem may be related to your ISP which has blocked accessing to google servers.

Answer (score 0):

My issues, is like the above,
i am trying to create a Flutter-Docker container

My error/output:

```
+2 ms] Failed to download https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/flutter/fonts/3012db47f3130e62f7cc0beabff968a33cbec8d8/fonts.zip. Ensure you have network connectivity and then try again.
```

#26 35.80            HandshakeException: Connection terminated during handshake

unfortunately i haven't resolved it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem with this method

FIXING INSTRUCTIONS:

1. Install Windows PowerShell 5
2. Install Git
3. Create folder as name as 'src' in C:\
4. Above executions should be in PowerShell or CommandPrompt(CMD)
5. Check 'git --version' is executing success.
6. Go to file directon 'C:\src'
7. Clone Flutter from git 'git clone [https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git'](https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git%27)
8. Check that Flutter files are cloned.
9. Execute health check Flutter command 'flutter doctor'
10. Execute version check Flutter command 'flutter --version'

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by restarting my computer. None of the previous solutions worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It my case, I checked my task manager and found out "flutter_test.exe" was running. Thus, it was actually using some file within "flutter/bin/cache" folder. Just finished that task and runned any flutter command such as "flutter --version". It worked.